# Function that checks for overflow in addition of unsigned ints

Tags: c

I have to make functions that check for overflow in integer addition, subtraction, and unsigned int addition(using only `! ~ | & ^ + >> <<`). I have functions figured out for signed integer addition and subtraction, but I can't figure out how to do one for unsigned int addition.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is the code I have for the 2 functions I have completed:

```
int twosAddOk(int x, int y){
    int z=x+y;
    int a=x>>31;
    int b=y>>31;
    int c=z>>31;
    return !!(a^b)|(!(a^c)&!(b^c));
}

int twosSubtractOK(int x, int y){
    int z=x+~y+1;
    return !(((x^y & x^z))>>31);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for the checks you have so far.

Comment: Unsigned addition should be the easiest

Comment: do you understand how numeric values are stored in `int`s in your c implementation? (almost certainly 2's complement)?

Comment: Do the calculation using a larger type, then check if the result is higher than the highest value of the original type.

Comment: @Barmar Looks like it will violate the constraints

Comment: added the code @kaylum

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948450/c-detect-unsigned-int-overflow-of-addition  I'll let others decide if this a duplicate or not.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I am not allowed to use if statements, only the operators i provided

Comment: @ians Why operator restriction?  What application needs that?  Looks like that would obfuscate code.

Comment: unsigned addition cannot overflow by definion. It can only wraparound

Comment: Your code uses the assignment operator `=`, which is not on the approved list.  (The point of this comment is that your restriction to use only those operators is silly.)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the carry-out from the MSB the hard way:

```
int unsignedAddOk(unsigned int x, unsigned int y){

    unsigned int x0=(~(1U<<31))&x; // MSB of x cleared
    unsigned int y0=(~(1U<<31))&y; // MSB of y cleared
    int c=(x0+y0)>>31; // Carry-in of MSB
    int a=x>>31; // MSB of x
    int b=y>>31; // MSB of y
    return !((a&b)|(a&c)|(b&c));
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks. Is it fixed now?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You're right. They are all actually boolean at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a solution without coding the magic number 31

```
// Return 1 on overflow
int unsigned_add_overflow_test(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
  // Add all but the LSBits and then add 1 if both LSBits are 1
  // When overflow would occur with a + b, sum's MSBit is set.
  unsigned sum = (a >> 1) + (b >> 1) + (a&b&1);
  // Test MSBit set
  //                vvv--------- All bits set
  return !!(sum & ~(-1u >> 1));
  //               ^^^^^^^^^^ -- All bits set, except MSBit
  //              ^^^^^^^^^^^ -- MSBit set, rest are 0 
}
```

Or as a one-liner

```
!!( ((a >> 1) + (b >> 1) + (a&b&1)) & ~(-1u >> 1)) )
```